# MutableSharedFlow is being re collected again and again

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, kotlin-sharedflow

I have the following ViewModel and Fragment -

```kotlin
class HeroesViewModel(private val heroesRepository: HeroesRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val internalUiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Initial)
    val uiState = internalUiState.asLiveData()

    private val internalUiAction = MutableSharedFlow<UiAction>(1).apply {
        tryEmit(UiAction.GetSuggestedList)
    }
    val uiAction = internalUiAction.asLiveData()

    private val externalUiEvent = MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>(1)
    private val uiEvent = externalUiEvent.asSharedFlow()

    init {
        observeUiEvents()
    }

    private fun observeUiEvents() = viewModelScope.launch {
        uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UiEvent.ListItemClicked -> {
                    navigateToHeroDetails(event.heroModel)
                }
                is UiEvent.SearchTextChanged -> {
                    getHeroesByName(event.searchText)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun navigateToHeroDetails(heroModel: HeroesListModel) =
        submitAction(UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails(heroModel))

    private fun getHeroesByName(name: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        when (val response = heroesRepository.getHeroesByNameWithSuggestions(name)) {
            is NetworkResponse.Success -> {
                internalUiState.emit(UiState.Data(response.body as List<HeroesListModel>))
            }

            is NetworkResponse.Error -> {
                response.error.message?.let { message ->
                    internalUiState.emit(UiState.Error(message))
                }
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }

    fun getSuggestedHeroesList() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        when (val response = heroesRepository.getSuggestedHeroesList(true)) {
            is NetworkResponse.Success -> {
                submitState(UiState.Data(response.body as List<HeroesListModel>))
            }

            is NetworkResponse.Error -> {
                response.error.message?.let { message ->
                    submitState(UiState.Error(message))
                }
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }

    private fun submitAction(uiAction: UiAction) = internalUiAction.tryEmit(uiAction)


    private fun submitState(uiState: UiState) = viewModelScope.launch {
        internalUiState.emit(uiState)
    }

    fun submitEvent(uiEvent: UiEvent) = externalUiEvent.tryEmit(uiEvent)

    sealed class UiEvent {
        data class SearchTextChanged(val searchText: String) : UiEvent()
        data class ListItemClicked(val heroModel: HeroesListModel) : UiEvent()
    }

    sealed class UiState {
        data class Data(val modelsListResponse: List<BaseHeroListModel>) : UiState()
        data class Error(val errorMessage: String) : UiState()
        object Initial : UiState()
    }

    sealed class UiAction {
        data class NavigateToHeroesDetails(val heroModel: HeroesListModel) : UiAction()
        object GetSuggestedList : UiAction()
    }
}

class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    //Class Variables - UI
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding

    //Class Variables - Dependency Injection
    private val heroesViewModel = get<HeroesViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        init()
        observeUiState()
        observeUiAction()
    }

    private fun observeUiAction() = heroesViewModel.uiAction.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { action ->
        when(action){
            is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.GetSuggestedList -> {
                getSuggestedHeroesList()
            }
            is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
                navigateToHeroesDetails(action.heroModel)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init() {
        binding.heroesSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : OnSearchViewOnlyTextChangedListener() {
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                if (newText.isNullOrEmpty()) return false
                heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.SearchTextChanged(newText))
                binding.progressBar.setVisiblyAsVisible()
                return false
            }

        })
    }

    private fun observeUiState() = heroesViewModel.uiState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { uiAction ->
        when (uiAction) {
            is HeroesViewModel.UiState.Data -> {
                showHeroesList(uiAction)
            }
            is HeroesViewModel.UiState.Error -> {
                showGeneralError(uiAction)
            }
            HeroesViewModel.UiState.Initial -> Unit
        }
    }

    private fun navigateToHeroesDetails(heroModel: HeroesListModel) =
        findNavController().navigate(DashboardFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToHeroesDetailsFragment(heroModel))


    private fun showHeroesList(result: HeroesViewModel.UiState.Data) {
        binding.heroesList.setContent {
            LazyColumn {
                items(result.modelsListResponse.toList()) { model ->
                    if (model is HeroListSeparatorModel)
                        HeroesListSeparatorItem(model)
                    else if (model is HeroesListModel)
                        HeroesListItem(model) {
                            heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.ListItemClicked(model))
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        binding.progressBar.setVisiblyAsGone()
    }

    private fun showGeneralError(result: HeroesViewModel.UiState.Error) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), result.errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        binding.progressBar.setVisiblyAsGone()
    }

    private fun getSuggestedHeroesList() {
        heroesViewModel.getSuggestedHeroesList()
        binding.progressBar.setVisiblyAsVisible()
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have the replayCache set to 1 in `internalUiAction` but the value keeps emitting itself. When I navigate using the `navigateToHeroesDetails()` method and go back using the navigation bar I immediately observe the last `uiAction` emitted value which is `NavigateToHeroesDetails`, causing me to navigate again and again to the heroes details screen. This is an endless loop of navigation.

As far as a hint for a solution, if I double tap the navigation 2 times quickly it does indeed go back to the first Fragment. Seems like I am missing something related to SharedFlow

Comment: With replayCache 1 last event gets re-emitted when new subscriber starts observing, if your design was to emit events set it to 0.

Comment: @Pawel but with 0 it doesn't emit anything at all at the first place